# Do humans start off with 1/3rd the languages of Other Races?

Tags: languages, starfinder, human

> A character begins play speaking and reading Common, her racial tongue
> (if any), and the language of her home planet (if any).

1. Common
2. Racial language: the human racial language is Common
3. Language of her home planet: The human world was destroyed. No Home planet.

This doesn't seem balanced. Am I reading this correctly? Every race except humans gets 3 languages, and the humans, who speak common, get common, and only common, modified by culture/intelligence bonuses?

EDIT: The Answer:

[Paizo's Example First Level Android](https://cdn.paizo.com/image/product/catalog/PZO/PZOCUP015E.jpg)

I was curious about more information and whether I was constructing characters correctly and found this reference. Apparently the android (also from the human civilization) only speaks Common. They have 12 intelligence which gave them +1 more language. They have 2 total languages listed:
Common, Shirren

So yes, apparently, humans have 1 starting language + int + cultures.
I hope this is useful for other people.

Answer (score 17):

While humans won't be able to get an additional language from race, as you describe, they could still have a second language by virtue of home planet. Everyone has a home planet: the planet they grew up on. Given that the human homeworld is gone, any human is going to be from some other planet, and will gain the language associated with that planet (If that happens to be Common as well, that particular human will have to deal with not being bilingual out the gate).

Answer (score -1):

Androids (see above edit containing link to Paizo Android example), also from the Human civilization, have exactly 1 language + intelligence modifiers: Common.

It therefore stands to reason that Home World and Racial Languages are bonuses. If your character has a specific home world, even if Human or Android, they might default have an extra language. But if they were born in a place where Common is the dominant language, like a space station or large cargo ship, you might have only 1 language.